# VB NET limit numeric in textbox

Tags: vb.net, textbox, numeric

I had created textbox in my program.
I need to ask user to input the value in textbox without using numeric control.
When they exceed the boundary numeric that I set, error message will pop out immediately.
How can I do that ?
Another methods also will appreciated!
Thanks You.

Answer (score 3):

Use `Int32.TryParse` and then check  if the value is  inside the boundaries.

```
Dim minimum = 10
Dim maximum = 100
Dim number As Int32
If Not Int32.TryParse(txtNumber.Text, number) Then
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid integer!")
    Return
End If
If number < minimum OrElse number > maximum Then
    Dim message = String.Format("Please enter an integer between {0} and {1}!",
                  minimum, maximum)
    MessageBox.Show(message)
    Return
End If

' all is ok, go on ...
```

Comment: How can I apply this in a keypress event? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

The answer given by @Tim Schmelter is correct, to get numbers on TextBox you should

check the DecimalUpdown class on  [Extend WPF Toolkit](https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=DecimalUpDown&referringTitle=Home)

:)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code I have used for years for DotNet textboxes.  You may need to change for your specific implementation but likely not.

Put this code in a module, so you can call it from multple places:

```
Public Sub NumericTextboxKeyPress(ByVal txt As TextBox, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs, Optional ByVal AllowNegative As Boolean = True, Optional ByVal AllowDecimal As Boolean = True)
        Dim dot As Boolean = False
        Dim flag As Boolean = False
        If e.KeyChar = ControlChars.Back Then
            Return
        End If
        If e.KeyChar = "."c AndAlso Not AllowDecimal Then
            flag = True
        End If
        If e.KeyChar = "-"c AndAlso Not AllowNegative Then
            flag = True
        End If
        If e.KeyChar = "."c And txt.Text.IndexOf("."c) > 0 Then
            dot = True
        End If
        If e.KeyChar < "-"c Or e.KeyChar > "9"c Or dot = True Then
            flag = True
        End If
        If txt.Text.Length > 0 AndAlso e.KeyChar = "-"c AndAlso (txt.SelectionStart > 0 OrElse txt.Text.IndexOf("-"c) >= 0) Then
            flag = True
        End If
        If e.KeyChar = "/"c Then
            flag = True
        End If
        If flag = True Then
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Function ValidNumericTextboxValue(ByVal txt As TextBox, ByVal Precision As Integer, ByVal Scale As Integer, ByVal Style As String, Optional ByVal ThrowError As Boolean = True) As Boolean
        If txt.Text Is Nothing OrElse txt.Text.Trim = "" Then
            txt.Text = Format(0, Style)
            Return True
        Else
            Dim Value As Object
            Dim dMax As Decimal
            Dim dMin As Decimal
            dMax = New String("9", Precision - Scale) & "." & New String("9", Scale)
            dMin = "-" & New String("9", Precision - Scale) & "." & New String("9", Scale)
            If IsNumeric(txt.Text) Then
                'Make sure there are not more digits after the decimal than allowed
                Value = Math.Round(CDec(txt.Text), Scale)
                If Value > dMax Then
                    If ThrowError Then
                        Throw New Exception("Numeric Value is geater than allowed!  Max value is: " & FormatNumber(dMax, Scale, TriState.False, TriState.UseDefault, TriState.True))
                    Else
                        MessageBox.Show("Numeric Value is geater than allowed!  Max value is: " & FormatNumber(dMax, Scale, TriState.False, TriState.UseDefault, TriState.True))
                    End If
                    Return False
                ElseIf Value < dMin Then
                    If ThrowError Then
                        Throw New Exception("Numeric Value is less than allowed!  Min value is: " & FormatNumber(dMin, Scale, TriState.False, TriState.UseDefault, TriState.True))
                    Else
                        MessageBox.Show("Numeric Value is less than allowed!  Min value is: " & FormatNumber(dMin, Scale, TriState.False, TriState.UseDefault, TriState.True))
                    End If
                    Return False
                End If
                'If I am here, lets format it and put it back in the textbox
                txt.Text = Format(Value, Style)
                Return True
            Else
                If ThrowError Then
                    Throw New Exception("This must be a numeric value!  Max value is: " & FormatNumber(dMax, Scale, TriState.False, TriState.UseDefault, TriState.True))
                Else
                    MessageBox.Show("This must be a numeric value!  Max value is: " & FormatNumber(dMax, Scale, TriState.False, TriState.UseDefault, TriState.True))
                End If
                Return False
            End If
        End If
    End Function
```

Call the `NumericTextboxKeyPress` method from the keypress event of the textbox, this will prevent them from typing special characters (non-numeric).

Call the `ValidNumericTextboxValue` from the validate event of the textbox.  This will format the text and validation precision and scale.

Enjoy